# Azure AD Service Principal Client Tokens Rotation with Azure DevOps Pipelines Service Connections - Is It Possible?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-principal

Are there any possible ways or best solution to automate or rotate Azure AD service principals client tokens used for Azure DevOps service connections?

Situation: Need to manually renew it and update all settings before it expires which is a manual process. I mark my calendars to remember, but a tedious manual task to remember.

I wonder if anybody in the community have tried using other implementations like using Azure Key Vault, Azure Functions, etc.

Thanks!

I tried to look for documentation but did not see some good example solutions or work-around for this.

Comment: You may have a look at this: https://koosg.medium.com/implement-automatic-key-rotation-on-azure-devops-service-connections-13804b92157c

Answer (score 0):

I too have implemented a version and some enhancements of https://koosg.medium.com/implement-automatic-key-rotation-on-azure-devops-service-connections-13804b92157c in our environment. Works great!